# Angular 2 ng2-bootstrap datepicker systemjs 404 error

Tags: angular, systemjs, angular2-directives, ng2-bootstrap

I am using datepicker from ng2-bootstrap.

https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/datepicker

I have imported DATEPICKER_DIRECTIVES in my component

```
import { DATEPICKER_DIRECTIVES } from './../../../node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker';
```

added it to directives list

```
directives: [DATEPICKER_DIRECTIVES],
```

and then in my template I am using it like this:

```
<datepicker [(ngModel)]="dt" [minDate]="minDate" [showWeeks]="true"></datepicker>
```

My systemjs configuration looks like this:

```
var map = {
        'app': 'content/app',
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
        '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
        "angular2-masonry": "node_modules/angular2-masonry",
        'datepicker': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker'
    };

var paths = {
        "masonry-layout": "node_modules/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.js",
        'datepicker': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker/datepicker.component.js',
    };


var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        "angular2-masonry": { defaultExtension: 'js', main: "index" },
        'datepicker': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: "datepicker.component" }
    };

var angularPackages = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router'
];

angularPackages.forEach(function (pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = {
        main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'
    };
});


var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages,
        paths: paths
    };

    System.config(config);
```

Everything compiles without any error, but when I run it in browser it displays below error in console:

```
/content/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker 404 (Not Found)
```

I am not sure why is it still searching for datepicker in /content/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker, I have specified to look in node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker.

Comment: How are you doing other component's import in your current file ? Let's say `import { Component } from '@angular/core';` , Is this way you doing it ? And I have a quick suggestion, why not use angular-cli for angular2 development ?

Comment: I am doing exactly like this import { Component } from '@angular/core'; , does angular-cli works with ASP.Net MVC projects as well (in visual studio)?

Comment: I am not a ASP.NET guy but it is nothing to do with ASP.NET . you will create api with whatever backend language you want, then your APIs will provide what ever your frontend angular2 project needs :) 
btw can you give a screenshot of your folder structure of node_modules

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure to include ng2-bootstrap library in your index.html:

```
<script src="node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```